# Problem removing parentheses characters from array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a fundamental text parser with python (because JavaScript is a nightmare for this kind of stuff apparently). I'm running into an issue with detecting parentheses in an array. Here is an example of the data set.

```
['0.0' '' '$15,448' '$15,114' '$48,966' '$47,338' '15,123' '11,705'
 '43,160' '32,937' '30,571' '26,819' '92,126' '80,275' '3,441' '3,425'
 '12,975' '11,903' '6,729' '5,844' '19,523' '16,708' '10,170' '9,269'
 '32,498' '28,611' '20,401' '17,550' '59,628' '51,664' '4,316' '3,715'
 '12,363' '10,793' '4,565' '4,335' '13,251' '12,709' '1,179' '1,208'
 '3,460' '3,483' '10,341' '8,292' '30,554' '24,679' ',' '145' '349' '538'
 '1,115' '10,486' '8,641' '31,092' '25,794' '1,677' '1,217' '5,039'
 '18,096' '$' '8,809' '$7,424' '$26,053' '$' '7,698' '$1.15' '$0.96'
 '$3.39' '$1.00' '$1.14' '$0.95' '$3.36' '$0.99' '7,672' '7,698' '7,679'
 '7,706' '7,744' '7,794' '7,759' '7,798' '.' '3' '1' '31,' '31,' '2019'
 '2018' '2019' '2018' '$8,809' '$7,424' '$26,053' '$7,698' ',' '33' '7'
 '93' '106' '714' '1,016' '1,334' '2,182' '67' '255' '252' '508' '748'
 '754' '989' '1,780' '$9,557' '$6,670' '$27,042' '$5,918' '.' '16' '.' '4'
 '1']
```

This array is created from a .txt file. I can test for whether or not the text has parentheses when reading the .txt file. But I can't for someone reason when iterating through the array.

```
def removeExcess():
    global numbers
    for num in numbers:
        if(num != ')' or num != '('):
            print(num)
```

Comment: `if(num != ')' or num != '(')` is *always* True - if it's one, it's not the other. Maybe you mean `and` rather than `or`? (Also note, conditions don't need parentheses in Python. And also also, you don't need a `global` declaration if you're not reassigning the name.)

Comment: I am reassigning. But yeah that worked. And I got rid of the excess parentheses, makes sense. I guess I'm not understanding the logic for some reason. 

Is it because of Python?

Comment: No that's just perfectly normal boolean logic. `or` is true if *either* of the conditions are true. So if num is ")", then `num != ')'` is false but `num != '('` is true, so the overall condition is true. And vice versa.

Comment: OH shoot. I guess the morning coffee is still kicking in. Thank you for rechecking my logic.